# Invoking a step function synchronously from a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda function which is triggered by a FIFO SQS. I only want one instance of the function running. The function invokes a state machine and the state machine takes longer to finish than the lambda function. I want the lambda function to finish only after the step function has completed it's execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Step Functions are only invoked asynchronously. A state machine can run for up to 1 year so synchronous invocation is not possible. Depending on your workflow you might find [Activities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html) useful.

> Activities are an AWS Step Functions feature that enables you to have
>   a task in your state machine where the work is performed by a worker
>   that can be hosted on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2),
>   Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS), mobile
>   devices—basically anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65137575/8553816 as posted at the bottom now step functions support synchronous transactions.

Answer (score 5):

AWS Express Step Functions now supports [synchronous invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/).

Keep in mind that Express Step Functions are meant for workloads that require higher event rates and have shorter durations. Also, keep in mind that you will be billed based on the number of requests and the duration of the workflow just like lambda.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect your state machine to complete in a reasonable time, then you can get your Lambda (or anything else that starts a state machine execution) to await a response.

This is an accepted pattern, but has quite a few moving parts:

- Set up an SNS topic; state machine results will be published onto it
- During your Lambda's initialisation:

  - generate a random "gateway ID"
  - create a SQS queue
  - subscribe to the SQS queue, filtering by gateway ID
- When your Lambda invokes the state machine:

  - generate a random "correlation ID"
  - include both the gateway and correlation IDs in the inputs to the state machine
- As the final step of the state machine, publish the result to the SNS topic.
  Include the gateway and correlation IDs in the response.
- In the lambda, after submitting the state machine execution:

  - await a message on the SQS queue.
  - give some thought to timeouts on this. You should set a timeout for the response. You can therefore set a time-to-live on the state machine -- if its outcome is going to be useless once this Lambda dies.
  - When it arrives, ensure that its correlation ID matches yours, then use the data in that message as your response.

Comment: This is a good solution. I am curious what would happen to the messages that the Lambda polls from SQS that does not match with the gateway and/or correlation IDs? Would the Lambda put them back without processing? Also, there could be multiple such Lambdas waiting for their own messages, which could be picked up by others. What are your thoughts on this?